# check company before delete if it exists in other tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

When I'm going to delete the record first it checks if the record id exist or not in other table? Now the code is working fine with one array key but when I add second array key it doesn't check the other one. My code is:

```
$response = checkCompaniesExisting($auctionCompanyId, array("auctionCompanyInOrders" => "auctionCompanyInOrders"));
```

First one is working fine but when I add second array key it doesn't work as per my requirment

```
$response = checkCompaniesExisting($companyId, array("clientInOrders" => "clientInOrders", "brokerAndShipperInBookings" => "brokerAndShipperInBookings"));
```

and my function is

```
function checkCompaniesExisting($recordId, $checkingCases) {
$responseArray = array();
foreach($checkingCases as $key => $value) {
    switch($key) {
        case 'clientInOrders':
            $checkClientInBookings = "SELECT clientId FROM ".DB_PREFIX."order WHERE clientId = '".$recordId."'";
            $checkClientInBookingsQuery = @mysql_query($checkClientInBookings);
            $checkClientInBookingsQueryArray = @mysql_fetch_assoc($checkClientInBookingsQuery);
            if($checkClientInBookingsQueryArray["clientId"] == $recordId) {
                $responseArray["response"] = "exist";
                $responseArray["responseText"] = "Client exists in orders";
            } else {
                $responseArray["response"] = "notExist";
            }
        break;

        case 'auctionCompanyInOrders':
            $checkAuctionCompanyInOrders = "SELECT auctionCompanyId FROM ".DB_PREFIX. "order WHERE auctionCompanyId = '".$recordId."'";
            $checkAuctionCompanyInOrdersQuery = @mysql_query($checkAuctionCompanyInOrders);
            $checkAuctionCompanyInOrdersQueryArray = @mysql_fetch_assoc($checkAuctionCompanyInOrdersQuery);
            if($checkAuctionCompanyInOrdersQueryArray["auctionCompanyId"] == $recordId) {
                $responseArray["response"] = "exist";
                $responseArray["responseText"] = "Auction company exists in orders";
            } else {
                $responseArray["response"] = "notExist";
            }
        break;

        case 'brokerAndShipperInBookings':
            $checkBrokerAndShipperInbookings = "SELECT bookingBrokerId, bookingShipperId FROM ".DB_PREFIX."bookings WHERE bookingBrokerId = '".$recordId."' OR bookingShipperId = '".$recordId."'";
            $checkBrokerAndShipperInbookingsQuery = @mysql_query($checkBrokerAndShipperInbookings);
            $checkBrokerAndShipperInbookingsQueryArray = @mysql_fetch_assoc($checkBrokerAndShipperInbookingsQuery);
            if($checkBrokerAndShipperInbookingsQueryArray["bookingBrokerId"] == $recordId || $checkBrokerAndShipperInbookingsQueryArray["bookingShipperId"] == $recordId) {
                $responseArray["response"] = "exist";
                $responseArray["responseText"] = "Broker OR Shipper exists in bookings";
            } else {
                $responseArray["response"] = "notExist";
            }
        break;
    }
}
return $responseArray;
}
```

Now the first array key `clientInOrders` is not working in `switch case` but the second one is working `brokerAndShipperInBookings` in switch case. what wrong with this code.

Comment: First of all, do not use `@` sign to hide the errors. And do not use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: ok I'll change the `mysql_*` function and remove `@`, but whats wrong with the code. Why it is not checking my first case.

Comment: It looks like you might be able to replace *all* this code with a foreign key that simply doesn't cascade deletes. Did you consider doing that?

Comment: No I didn't do that.

Comment: Is any one available and solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are always overwrite your result `array` keys.

In the foreach loop, add the `$key` to your result array to create a multidimensional associative array. This is only one of them in loop, do this for others too.

```
           if ($checkAuctionCompanyInOrdersQueryArray["auctionCompanyId"] == $recordId) {
                $responseArray[$key]["response"] = "exist";
                // Added $key ^^^^^^
                $responseArray[$key]["responseText"] = "Auction company  exists in orders";
                // Added $key ^^^^^^
            } else {
                $responseArray[$key]["response"] = "notExist";
                // Added $key ^^^^^^
            }
```

I've added a `$key` to your array. Try this.
After this, try `var_dump($responseArray);` to debug.

Comment: How I handle this `if($response["response"] != "exist") { //delete code }` after add `$key` in my loop.

Comment: `$response['clientInOrders']['response']` This is why I sad, `var_dump` it to see the new structure of your `array`.

Comment: I just change the `keys` and `value` and also use `$value` in `switch case` and its working fine now. Thanks

Comment: Now I'm going to change the function of `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`.